# Mysql - Show one row if table1.id = table2.id > 1

Tags: mysql

Well, I have 3 tables.
1. Products
2. Product Barcodes + Quantity
3. Product Categories

What I want to display is Single product with the total amount of quantity and category.

```
dfs_product_id
-------------------
|ID|Name|Ldate|Cat|
-------------------
|1 |AA  |2    |2  |
|2 |BB  |3    |3  |
|3 |CC  |1    |1  |
-------------------
```

```
dfs_product_quantity
------------------------
|ID|PID|Pqw|Pqs|Barcode|
------------------------
|1 |1  |10 |5  |123456 |
|2 |2  |10 |5  |654321 |
|3 |3  |10 |5  |789456 |
|4 |2  |8  |2  |654987 |
|5 |3  |15 |14 |741852 |
|6 |1  |11 |14 |258147 |
------------------------
```

```
dfs_product_category

---------
|ID|Name|
---------
|1 |GH  |
|2 |TD  |
|3 |KL  |
---------
```

```
    SELECT
        dfs_product_id`.`ID` AS 'Product ID',
        dfs_product_id`.`Name`,
        dfs_product_id`.`Ldate` AS 'Last UpDate',
        (
            SELECT
                SUM(`dfs_product_quantity`.`Pqw`)
            FROM
                `dfs_product_quantity`
            WHERE
                `dfs_product_quantity`.`PID` = `dfs_product_id`.`ID`
        ) AS 'Stock In Web',
        (
            SELECT
                SUM(`dfs_product_quantity`.`Pqs`)
            FROM
                `dfs_product_quantity`
            WHERE
                `dfs_product_quantity`.`PID` = `dfs_product_id`.`ID`
        ) AS 'Stock In Store',
        `dfs_product_category`.`Name` AS 'Category' 
    FROM
        `dfs_product_id`,
        `dfs_product_quantity`,
        `dfs_product_category` 
    WHERE
        `dfs_product_id`.`ID` = `dfs_product_quantity`.`PID`
    AND
        `dfs_product_id`.`Cat` = `dfs_product_category`.`ID` 
    AND
        ( 'Stock In Web' + 'Stock In Store' ) < '50' 
    ORDER BY
        `dfs_product_id`.`Ldate` DESC 
    LIMIT 0 , 50
```

This code Displays :

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
|Product ID|Name|Last UpDate|Stock in Web|Stock in Store|Category|
------------------------------------------------------------------
|2         |BB  |3          |18          |7             |KL      |
|2         |BB  |3          |18          |7             |KL      |
|1         |AA  |2          |21          |19            |DT      |
|1         |AA  |2          |21          |19            |DT      |
|3         |CC  |1          |25          |19            |GH      |
|3         |CC  |1          |25          |19            |GH      |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What, I want is to show the total amount on Stock in web and Stock in store, ID, Name, LastUpDate, and category name.
And if have more then one quantity record of the product, just show one row and count total in Stock in Web and Stock in Store.

Comment: Can you create the expected results as a ascii data table as well so we can verify our query? Also because a data table tells more and is more clear then your explainment..

Comment: But it feels like you are asking for `DISTINCT` here?  `SELECT DISTINCT
    dfs_product_id.ID AS 'Product ID',
    dfs_product_id.Name,
    dfs_product_id.Ldate AS 'Last UpDate',
    (`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "Group By" in your query

```
SELECT
DISTINCT  dfs_product_id.ID AS 'Product ID',
dfs_product_id.Name,
dfs_product_id.Ldate AS 'Last UpDate',
(
    SELECT
        SUM(dfs_product_quantity.Pqw)
    FROM
        dfs_product_quantity
    WHERE
        dfs_product_quantity.PID = dfs_product_id.ID  
) AS 'Stock In Web',
(
    SELECT
        SUM(dfs_product_quantity.Pqs)
    FROM
        dfs_product_quantity
    WHERE
        dfs_product_quantity.PID = dfs_product_id.ID 
) AS 'Stock In Store',
dfs_product_category.Name AS 'Category' FROM
dfs_product_id,
dfs_product_quantity,
dfs_product_category WHERE
dfs_product_id.ID = dfs_product_quantity.PID AND
dfs_product_id.Cat = dfs_product_category.ID AND ( 'Stock In Web' + 'Stock In Store' ) < '50' 
GROUP by Category ORDER BY dfs_product_id.Ldate DESC LIMIT 0 , 50
```

will show this result [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the query quite a bit. No need for subqueries nested in SELECT. Note also that you shoud compare to numeric 50 not string '50'.

```
SELECT
  pid.ID AS 'Product ID',
  pid.Name,
  pid.Ldate AS 'Last UpDate',
  SUM(pq.Pqw) AS 'Stock In Web',
  SUM(pq.Pqs) AS 'Stock In Store',
  pc.Name AS 'Category' 
FROM dfs_product_id pid
  JOIN dfs_product_category pc on pid.Cat = pc.ID 
  JOIN dfs_product_quantity pq on pq.PID = pid.ID
GROUP BY pid.ID, pid.Name, pid.Ldate, pc.Name
HAVING SUM(pq.Pqw) + SUM(pq.Pqs) < 50
ORDER BY pid.Ldate DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 50
```